# Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, omnisharp

I  am trying to solve this below omnisharp issue last 3 days. But not solve yet

I followed many solution but anything is not work for me.

Below I mentioned what I did as this link
https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1941159

I did reinstall vs code, extensions, downgrade extensions.

Added a global.json, changed setting.json as below mentioned.

exported into ~/.bashrc file. as below mentioned
And

- I have install mono and I addd  into setting.json this line `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always",` . But got another warn in Omnisharp log  as
  `[warn]: OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder It looks like you have Mono installed which contains a MSBuild lower than 16.7.0 which is the minimum supported by the configured .NET Core Sdk.`

Then I add "msbuild": { "useBundledOnly": true }, into ominsharp.json. The above mentioned warning has gone.
But Still
fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

**Ubuntu : 20.04   ,
vs code version : 1.63.2**

**which dotnet**

output:

`/usr/bin/dotnet`

**$ dotnet --info**

output:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):

 Version:   6.0.101

 Commit:    ef49f6213a



Runtime Environment:

 OS Name:     ubuntu

 OS Version:  20.04

 OS Platform: Linux

 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64

 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/



Host (useful for support):

  Version: 6.0.1

  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc



.NET SDKs installed:

  3.1.416 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

  5.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

  5.0.209 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

  5.0.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

  6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]



.NET runtimes installed:

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]



To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:

  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

$ xdg-open ~/.bashrc
output:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export DOTNET_ROOT=/snap/dotnet-sdk/current

export FrameworkPathOverride=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current

export MSBuildSDKsPath =/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/Sdks

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet
```

**omnisharp.json**

`{ "msbuild": { "useBundledOnly": true }, "UseLegacySdkResolver": true }`

**global.json**

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.101",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

**setting.json**

```
{
 "omnisharp.path": "latest",
  "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never",
  "omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout": 600
}
```

**OmniSharp Log:**

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 01/01/2022, 23:33:28
Target: /home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/TechneTravel.sln

OmniSharp server started with Mono 6.12.0.
Path: /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
PID: 10445

Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 20.4 (x64)
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
DotNetPath set to dotnet
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
Because 'UseBundledOnly' is enabled in the configuration, OmniSharp will only use the bundled MSBuild.
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
1: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe'
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
CscToolExe = csc.exe
MSBuildToolsPath = /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
CscToolPath = /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0/.omnisharp/1.37.18-beta.120/omnisharp/.msbuild
info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer

////// removed some for short

[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Domain/Domain.csproj
A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [6.0.101] from [/home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] was not found.
Install the [6.0.101] .NET SDK or update [/home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Domain/Domain.csproj'.
 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Domain/Domain.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Application/Application.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj
```

and I remove some line in this log, I created an issue on GitHub https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4985. You can see the Full omnisharp Log in this link

Please help to solve this issue. I had tried to solve last few days.
Please help me

Comment: Have you tried not using the global mono? What about the non-bundled msbuild?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned about mono in the question.
I fixed it this issue by installing version 1.24.0 https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.24.0-beta1